# Why is this non-stationary series diagnosed as stationary by adfuller test in python?

Tags: python, time, series

I simulated a time series model x_t = -1.1x_t-1+e_t in python. By visually checking the time series plot, I think that it should be non-stationary. Because the variance increases as time going by. However, the p-value of adffuler approaches zero, indicating that this series should be stationary. Can anyone help me and let me know if this is a stationary or non-stationary series? Which evidence (visual plot versus adftest) should I rely on to check the stationarity? Thank you very much for any help in advance.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
n = int(1000)
alphas = np.array([-1.1])
betas = np.array([0.])
ar = np.r_[1, -alphas[i]]
ma = np.r_[1, betas[i]]
np.random.seed(12345)
ar_data = smt.arma_generate_sample(ar=ar, ma=ma, nsample=n)
adf_result = adfuller(ar_data)
print (adf_result)
plt.plot(ar_data)
plt.plot_acf(ar_data)
plt.plot_pacf(ar_data)
```

> > > print (adf_result)
> > >       (-1.0861168664712843e+17, 0.0, 14, 985, {'1%': -3.4370062675076807, '5%': -2.8644787205542492, '10%': -2.568334722615888}, 111772.54850986988)

[image]

Comment: From the wikipedia page on this test: **The augmented Dickey–Fuller (ADF) statistic, used in the test, is a negative number. The more negative it is, the stronger the rejection of the hypothesis that there is a unit root at some level of confidence.** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test. So your very tiny negative value is telling you that this is not a stationary series.

Comment: The more negative it is, the stronger that we should reject the null hypothesis. My understanding about adftest is that -- the null hypothesis indicates non-stationarity while the the alternative hypothesis represents stationarity. So the very tiny negative p-value hints us to reject the null hypothesis. That said, the alternative hypothesis holds, meaning this is a stationary series, right?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's a misunderstanding, correct me if I'm wrong. The series should be non-stationary: (i) ADF Statistic (-1.086e+17) is lower than the critical values:{'1%': -3.43, '5%': -2.86, '10%': -2.56}. the credibility we give is little, and (ii) p_value is close to 0.0 maybe there is a problem os autocorrelation and the Augmented Dickey Fuller Test is not the most appropiated. Correct me if I'm wrong, pls. In fact, in the ACF plot yoy can observes some kind of structured ....